# Django; How to filter and make objects distinct

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a project using Django and I'm wondering how I can make objects distinct. Now I am creating message box part and what I want to do is show up user names who the user have been contacting. My current way is like this

`models.py`

```
class Message(models.Model):
    ''''''
    text = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='myself')
    someone = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='someone')
```

`views.py`

```
def inbox(request):
    '''See messages history'''
    messages = Message.objects.filter(user=request.user).distinct('someone')
    notification = Message.objects.filter(someone=request.user).distinct('user')
    return render(request, 'campus_feed/inbox.html', {'messages': messages})
```

So what I want to do is list the users who is contacting me or I contacted and I don't want to show up the same name multiple times but I cannot come up with good way to filter them. Anyone who can give me tips?

Comment: Hm, maybe you looking for `messages = Message.objects.filter(user=request.user).distinct()`? This will return all messages where `user` is `request.user` without repetition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want users, you should request users.

```
User.objects.filter(Q(myself__someone=request.user) | Q(someone__user=request.user))
```

This gives you all users who are either the "someone" in a message from the current user, or the "user" in a message to the current user. Since you are querying users directly, the is no possibility of duplicates.

Comment: I am not convinced that a `User` can not be returned multiple times. Since we here perform a `JOIN` on the `message` table, it could happen that a user has send us multiple messages, or that we have send a message, and the user responded. As a result a user can occur several times.

Comment: Yes but this is a simple SELECT on users with an OR. By definition in SQL, a SELECT won't return the same row multiple times even if it matches multiple criteria.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but it can match *multiple messages*. So hence every user is returned the number of times he/she appears in the message. If we have two users `Alice` and `Bob`, and the `request.user` is `Alice`, then if `Bob` has send `Alice` three messages, `Bob` will occur three times in the `QuerySet`. After all in SQL, this is a JOIN so the "implicit" table over which we fiter is *M x N* rows large, (with *N* the number of users, and *M* the number of messages), or taking the JOINs into account *M* rows. The OR will prevent to "select" the *same* message twice.